# How to access class instance from within the inline declaration?

Tags: django, django-admin

I think this is best understood with an example:

Pizzas and Toppings have a many to many relationship. I want to display a Pizza's toppings in a TabularInline.

```
class ToppingInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Pizza.toppings.through
    fields = ('topping',)
    extra = 0
    if not model.topping.count():
        classes = ['collapse']
```

As you can see, I only want to collapse the tabular inline if there are no toppings on the pizza.

The code `model.topping.count()` does not work though. The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Do you know how I can accomplish *if no toppings on the pizza, collapse the tabular inline*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `model` should be `Toppings`.

```
class ToppingInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Toppings
```

To conditionally set classes on your InlineModelAdmin you need to override a method that takes the object, django does not provide a method specifically for this functionality but I have overridden `get_formset` as an example

```
def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if not obj or not obj.toppings.count():
        self.classes = ['collapse']
    return super(ToppingInlineAdmin, self).get_formset(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I appreciate it.